# PostgreSQL select method like excel

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: postgresql select get the same id]

when i handle BI data，I found the same data is not i need，so，i want use postgresql handle data，
I want get the reuslt like this style,the postgesql select how write ?

[image]

```
    -- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for data_test
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."data_test";
CREATE TABLE "public"."data_test" (
  "c_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "n_id" int4,
  "b_id" int4
)
;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of data_test
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (58748, 587, 55);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (5895, 587, 55);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (12131, 567, 53);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (33412, 568, 54);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (5841, 569, 52);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (587, 500, 51);
INSERT INTO "public"."data_test" VALUES (5871, 500, 51);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select c_id, n_id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by n_id order by c_id) = 1
             then b_id
        end) as b_id
from data_test
order by n_id, c_id;
```

Note that this returns `NULL` rather then `-` -- which is what I assume you actually intend by `-` given that `-` is not compatible with `int4`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=58331595caa957d1f9487d624ff198a2) is a db<>fiddle.